# Trajectory of a particle for $t\ge1$ given $r(t)$ for $0\le t \le 1$.

Tags: calculus, vectors, parametric

I have a question on the process for which to solving this question. It is a homework question, and I already have the answer, but I am not sure on the correct process to attaining that answer.

The question in full:

> A particle has position given by $r(t)=\left<3t, 5t^2, 3t^3 \right>$ at time $t$ for 
>   $0 \le t \le 1$. At time $t = 1$ the particle departs the curve and flies off along the 
>   line tangent to the curve at $r(1)$. If the particle maintains a constant speed given by 
>   $|v(1)|$, what is the trajectory for the particle for $t\ge 1$.

My process:

So first I thought I'd get the position at $t=1$, and find $r'(t)$ in order to find $|v(1)|$
($r'(1)$).

$r(t)=\left<3t, 5t^2, 3t^3 \right>$ $\space$ $r(1)= \left< 3, 5, 3 \right>$

$r'(t)=\left<3, 10t, 9t^2 \right>$  $\space$ $r'(1)= \left< 3, 10, 9 \right>$

So having these, I thought I'd just set up parametric equations for the new trajectory and got $x=3+3t, y=5+10t, z=3+9t$ and in turn got the new position vector function to be $r(t)=\left<3+3t, 10t+5, 3+9t \right>$. But the answer is $r(t)=\left<3t, 10t-5, 9t-6 \right>$ and that is wrong, so I'm not sure on how to go about getting those values. Thanks for all the help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did everything right except for one thing. If you'd like to find the position at $t \geq 1$, you start with $r(1)$ as you correctly did, and add $t-1$ times $r'(1)$. Why $t-1$ and not $t$? Because $t-1$ is exactly how much time passes since $t=1$. So the parametrization is

\begin{align}
r(t) &= r(1)+(t-1)r'(1)\\\\
&=\left<3,5,3\right>+(t-1)\left<3,10,9\right>\\\\
&=\left<3+3t-3,5+10t-10,3+9t-9\right>\\\\
&=\boxed{\left<3t,10t-5,9t-6\right>}\\
\end{align}

---

What you calculated was $r(1)+tr'(1)$.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks a lot. Great explanation.

Comment: Yeah, that's right.  What Zubin said.  Cheers!